# Commenter should see only his comments in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, comments

I'm building a site for a research and my participants will be all logged in to use the site. 
I would like to make these participants able to see only their own comments, so other users' comments will be hidden.

I'm using the comments.php file with, among other things, this simple code:

```
<?php if ( have_comments() ) : ?>

      <ol class="commentlist">
          <?php wp_list_comments(); ?>
      </ol>

      <?php if ( ! comments_open() ) : ?>
          <p class="no-comments">Comments are closed</p>
      <?php endif; ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

What do I need to place around this code to filter the comments and show them only to their owners? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit the comments template and use a combination of this

```
get_comment(get_comment_ID())->user_id;
```

which returns the user id of whoever commented, and compare it to the current user with

```
get_current_user_id();
```

Both return 0 if the commenter wasn't registered or if the current user isn't logged in, respectively.

Comment: Thanks, but I forgot to mention that I'm not a programmer and I don't know php syntax :-/ I know that it will be something like: get the current user, check if there's a comment from the current user on the current post, if true then show comment. But how to write this in php?

Comment: Sorry, I can't write the code for you, but maybe someone else will.

Comment: Thanks, I'll ask it elsewhere.