# users see only their comment in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Is there any way that users see only their comment in wordpress?

I reade this topic:
[Commenter should see only his comments in wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26618989/commenter-should-see-only-his-comments-in-wordpress)

but it is not useful.

regards

the code for the comments template:

```
<ol class="comment-list"> 
    <?php wp_list_comments( array( 'style' => 'ol', 'short_ping' => true, ) ); ?> 
</ol><!-- .comment-list -->
```

Comment: why not? the solution in this link is what you're looking for

Comment: I don't know php :|

Comment: check my answer here

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to modify a default wordpress setting - in this case php is more than necessery. the solution in the link you've attached is the simplest and most elegent - if it's that important hire a dev to do this for you.

that's some sample code:

```
<ol class="comment-list">
    <?php $user_id = get_current_user_id();
        $user_comments = get_comments( 'user_id' => $user_id );
        wp_list_comments( 
            array( 'style' => 'ol', 'short_ping' => true, ), 
        $user_comments ); ?> 
</ol>
```

Comment: why not in your question? please style it and put in question

Comment: the site is not loading. i'm sorry but i won't be able to assist you with this more than i have. my friend, hire a dev.